# How to add an input file uploader in customer registration form in Prestashop v1.6

Tags: file-upload, prestashop-1.6, user-registration, required-field

I want **to add an input file uploader in customer registration form
in Prestashop v1.6.**
This document is required to account creation.I'm stuck for days..
I've added lines to authentification.tpl around line 131 like this :

```
<div class="required form-group">  
                <label for="carte_pro">{l s='Upload Professionnal card :'}<sup>*</sup></label>
                <input type="file" class="is_required validate form-control" data_validate="isFichiercorrect" id="carte_pro" name="carte_pro" value="{if isset($smarty.post.carte_pro)}{$smarty.post.carte_pro}{/if}" />
                <p>{l s='Valid extensions are doc,pdf,jpg,jpeg and png.'}</p>               
                </div>
```

Then around line 464 :

```
<div class="required form-group">
            <label for="carte_pro">{l s='Upload Professionnal card :'} <sup>*</sup></label>
            <input onkeyup="$('#carte_pro').val(this.value);" type="file" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isFichiercorrect" id="customer_carte_pro" name="carte_pro" value="{if isset($smarty.post.carte_pro)}{$smarty.post.carte_pro}{/if}" />
        </div>
```

Then I overrided customer.php by ading thoses lines :
around line 30 : `public$carte_pro;`
and around line 68 :
 `'carte_pro' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isFichiercorrect', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),`

Then I overrided the Validate.php file by adding at the end :

```
**
 * Validation carte_pro
 * @static
 */
public static function isFichiercorrect($carte_pro)
{
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/', $name);
}
```

I precise that i generated inbetween an Sql request to create my field like this :`ALTER TABLE ps_customer ADD`carte_pro`VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`
The thing is, that nothing really works. I'd appreciate your precious help considering that I've past so many hours to solve this..I would be great to be notified in back office and able to display there the document..Please help xx

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked is your registration form has:  `enctype='multipart/form-data'`